# How to implement highcharts navigator with 24HR and weekly zoom filter?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, visualization

I tried to get the highcharts navigator to contain weekly and 24HR zoom filters. But had no luck so far. Can anybody point out how I can accomplish that? Thank you.

Link to highcharts navigator example: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/navigator

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, what you want to do is change the buttons on your chart. By editing rangeSelector.buttons you can achieve that. The example from the API seems to have exactly what you are asking for (week and day):

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/datagrouping/

```
rangeSelector: {
  allButtonsEnabled: true,
  buttons: [{
    type: 'month',
    count: 3,
    text: 'Day',
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [['day', [1]]]
    }
  }, {
    type: 'year',
    count: 1,
    text: 'Week',
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [['week', [1]]]
    }
  }, {
    type: 'all',
    text: 'Month',
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [['month', [1]]]
    }
  }],
  buttonTheme: {
    width: 60
  },
  selected: 2
}
```

**API on rangeSelector.buttons**: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttons